# Dimension from inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Let $S$ denote $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3$, which satisfies the inequalities:
$$x - 2y + z \leq 1$$

$$2x + 2y - z \leq 5$$

$$-2x + y + z \leq 4$$

$$x \geq 1$$

$$y \geq 2$$

$$z \geq 3$$

How do I find the dimension of S?

I have tried to transform the inequalities into matrix form, but I'm not quite sure that this is even the right way.

Comment: Related to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1838508/86776

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedron#Convex_polyhedra and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polytope#Intersection_of_half-spaces

Comment: How does it help me?